# Wait till R restarts

Tags: r

I am using command `.rs.restartR()` to restart R in automation of my project. It restores loaded R packages and dataframes. How can I make R understand that `.rs.restartR()` has been executed, go to the next line of code. `if(3>2) {.rs.restartR(); print('Hello World')}` Can it be done using `system( )` command?

Comment: Why restart R for this rather than use rscript or littler or something to create a new R process where you can pass in parameters if needed?

Comment: I am using chromote package which uses processx to run background process. Sometimes it hangs which needs R to be restarted. It impacts automation so restart R is the only option I found from github issues.

Comment: Write a memo file and check for it’s existence.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what is a memo file? Any example would be helpful.